# Dataset to train MITIE ner model

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, rasa-nlu

Is there any existing dataset with tagged entities to train MITIE ner model? 
I checked the link, https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE/blob/master/examples/python/train_ner.py which trains the model with just two samples. Is there any existing dataset with tagged entities to train ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been looking for something like this, too. Simply for a "generic" (and hence not very useful) NLU backend. The only thing I've found so far is a trained model with 9 news categories (not very generic). See blog post here: http://eric-yuan.me/ner_1/

If you have the option to switch NERs, spaCy has a trained model available by default. Its visualisation front end can be found by google "displacy"

If you find anything else, let me know!

**EDIT:** Spent the day looking into this and I think I've found what you're after. If you go to https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE/releases there you'll find MITIE's own NER model trained on Wikipedia, Freebase, etc. The actual training dataset is there too. The README on their github page provides example on how to use the pre-trained model. You can also investigate the ner.py file in the examples folder to see how to use the pre-trained model in python code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will comment here if I find any other useful dataset.

Comment: I tried to create my own dataset with tagged entities by clustering the glove vectors and tagging each cluster with a name. Do you think this is a correct approach?

Comment: It sounds like it but I haven't played around with this stuff yet to be sure. And it looks like I won't be coming back to this for awhile now because I've been assigned to another project. You're on your own for the time being. Sorry :(